# Python: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys' when dictionary has bad value

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to use json_normalize to convert a nested dictionary to a DataFrame. I was able to do so successfully, until I ignorederrors on some results.

Long story short - i am using Youtube-dl in python to scrape a youtube channel, then i am converting the resulting data into a DF. Whenever the youtube video errors, i ignore it in youtube-dl and proceed to the next one. I think that is creating a bad dictionary entry which causes my json_normalize to fail.

here is how i get my channel data

```
!pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
import youtube_dl 
import pandas as pd
import json


church = input('enter the name of the church')
method = 'y'
channelID = input('enter channel url ending in videos')


with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'ignoreerrors' : True}) as ydl:
  result = ydl.extract_info(
    str(channelID),
    download=False,
  )
```

I then convert `result` into a DF with the below snippet

```
import json



data = pd.json_normalize(
  result, 
  record_path =['entries'],
  errors='ignore'
)
```

However, because some of the videos were skipped due to youtube errors, i get the below error everytime i run the json_normalize function

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-e3aa31b503f3> in <module>()
     19   result,
     20   record_path =['entries'],
---> 21   errors='ignore'
     22 )

4 frames
pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    635     """
    636     if columns is None:
--> 637         gen = (list(x.keys()) for x in data)
    638         sort = not any(isinstance(d, dict) for d in data)
    639         columns = lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen(gen, sort=sort)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Can someone advise on what i need to do to account for those bad dictionary entries?

Comment: Well, if you think the problem is caused by something returning `None`, what happened when you tried writing code to *check* whether `None` was returned, and *do something different* in that case?

Comment: HI Karl - apologies, I am not sure how to check where the None issue is coming from. So far I've been trying for 6 hours :/

Comment: Well, you said that "I then convert `result` into a DF with the below snippet", and this causes the error to happen. So... maybe, just maybe, `result` is the thing that is `None` and shouldn't be? Either that, or *something contained within it*. What happened when you *tried checking that*? Obviously there is *something* wrong with `result`, or the conversion would work normally. So if you want to figure out what is wrong, then the first step is to understand what the `result`s should look like, and then check for something abnormal. Right?

Comment: Another step you can take is to try *reading the documentation*, so that you understand what the `result` should look like. You can also confirm that it *makes sense* to try to convert the `result` into a `DataFrame` (I'm not sure why you expect this to make sense).

Answer (score 2):

Can you not prescreen your data list with something like:

```
data = [x for x in data if x is not None]
```

Comment: Same error when adding that in

````
data = [x for x in data if x is not None]
````

Comment: I don't understand where the `NoneType` came from if you filtered them out of your data list.